# Como adicionar parâmetros no action html?

Tags: javascript, html

Agora há pouco perguntei sobre os links da topbar do meu site. Bem, agora o problema é outro: adicionar parâmetros a uma url. Segue o código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function web(){
document.form.action = "http://www.google.com.br/search?q=";
}
function images(){
document.form.action = "http://www.google.com.br/search?q=";
}
function videos(){
document.form.action = "http://www.google.com.br/search?q=";
}
function news(){
document.form.action = "http://www.google.com.br/search?q=";
}
</script>
```

O parâmetro da pesquisa do Google por:

`imagens: &tbm=isch`, `vídeos: &tbm=vid`, `notícias: &tbm=nws`.

Como faço para adicionar estes parâmetros na url?

Comment: Pode explicar melhor o que quer fazer? e o que já tentou?

Comment: Quero adicionar o parâmetro &tbm=isch na url de pesquisa do google no meu formulário sem afetá-la. Ex: http://www.google.com.br/search?q=suapesquisa&tbm=isch

Answer (score 2):

### "A ordem dos parâmetros não altera o produto" :)

Os pares de parâmetro são separados por `&`, mas na maior parte das aplicações, a ordem em que você os apresenta, é irrelevante. Assim, basta usar o formato abaixo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function web(){
   document.form.action = "http://www.google.com.br/search?q=";
}
function images(){
   document.form.action = "http://www.google.com.br/search?tbm=isch&q=";
}
function videos(){
   document.form.action = "http://www.google.com.br/search?tbm=vid&q=";
}
function news(){
   document.form.action = "http://www.google.com.br/search?tbm=nws&q=";
}
</script>
```

Exemplo de link: http://www.google.com.br/search?tbm=isch&q=M.C.Escher

**Nota:** isto só faz sentido se você for chamar a função por JS, pois se quiser aproveitar os campos de um form normal, não deveria estar mandando nem o `tbm` nem o `q` no `action`, e sim como campos.

Comment: Agora fiquei curioso... Você já viu alguma Aplicação na qual a ordem dos parâmetros GET influencia em alguma coisa?

Comment: @BrunoAugusto sim, tem uma empresa de cobrança por boletos e cartão no Brasil que teve a capacidade de usar parse posicional de string tanto pra XML quanto QueryString. Basta mudar a ordem dos parâmetros (ou dos nodes na mesma profundidade), e o treco falha. Claro que isso é gambiarra deles, se tivessem seguido a especificação isso nunca aconteceria (mas já vi acontecer em mais de um caso).

Comment: @BrunoAugusto lembrei também de uma empresa "chipeira" de SMS que sofre do mesmo mal na API de envio de mensagens. Os parâmetros do GET tem que ser na ordem. Pena que eu não posso dizer o nome aqui :)

Comment: @BrunoAugusto Já vi vários sistemas que usam array de parâmetros. Por exemplo, se houver uma tabela com vários checkboxes: `item=1&item=5&item=7`. Então isso é recuperado numa lista no lado do servidor que poderioa considerar a ordem dos itens.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa adicionar um `<input type="hidden" name="tbm">` dentro do seu `<form>`, depois pode fazer assim:

```
document.form.tbm.value = "isch";
```

ou

```
document.form.elements["tbm"].value = "isch";
```

Desta forma, seu código ficaria assim:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function web(){
    document.form.action = "http://www.google.com.br/search";
}
function images(){
    document.form.action = "http://www.google.com.br/search";
    document.form.tbm.value = "isch";
}
function videos(){
    document.form.action = "http://www.google.com.br/search";
    document.form.tbm.value = "vid";
}
function news(){
    document.form.action = "http://www.google.com.br/search";
    document.form.tbm.value = "nws";
}
</script>
```

Referência: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_form_name.asp

Comment: eu gosto da sua solução, mas seria legal você editar a resposta e colocar o código do OP adaptado para o que você está explicando, valorizaria bastante a sua explicação.

Comment: Muito Obg! Funcionou! Mas estas funções são chamadas por link, e quando clicamos neles, a search-box perde o foco. Tem como manter ela selecionada?

Comment: @GustavoBarbosa para manter o foco em um elemento, use `document.getElementById("idDoElemento").focus();`.